# Is it a bug that post score differ in user's page and post page?

Tags: discussion, bug, up-votes, score

I noticed this in a user's page (the top post has a 28 score):

[image: User page]

But in the post page it has a score of 27.

[image: Post page]

Of course, before I up-voted it, the score was still 28 in the user's page.

Comment: It would be helpful if you linked to the pages.

Comment: I see both as 27

Comment: I think it was a bug for me. Now I see both as $27$.